# Build strongswan-systemd using the "apt-get" repo on Ubuntu

Tags: systemd, strongswan

I have built strongswan using the legacy ipsec interface, however reading the following document I am able to build the newer version with the systemd unit file approach:

https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Charon-systemd

I'd quite like to use a package manager for this task rather than the autotools approach, however when I use

```
sudo apt-get install strongswan-swantctl
```

It looks like it is just the high-level interface I'm getting and no unit files - so am unable to manage with systemctl.

Answer (score 1):

The `charon-systemd` daemon is contained in the `charon-systemd` package, which also contains a systemd unit file. It will also automatically install the `strongswan-swanctl` package, which provides the plugin and utility necessary to manage the daemon via [swanctl](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Swanctl)/[vici](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Vici).